# Kinesis agent not parsing the file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have the following in the agent.json

```
{
  "cloudwatch.emitMetrics": true,
  "kinesis.endpoint": "",
  "firehose.endpoint": "", 
  "flows": [
    {
      "filePattern": "/home/ec2-user/ETLdata/contracts/Delta.csv",
      "kinesisStream": "ETL-rawdata-stream",
      "partitionKeyOption": "RANDOM",
      "dataProcessingOptions": [
        {
    "optionName": "CSVTOJSON",
    "customFieldNames": [ "field1", "field2"],
    "delimiter": ","
        }
      ] 
    }
  ]
}
```

When I add the specified file to the folder, literally nothing happens. I only see the below in the logs. Why is it not parsing the file at all. Does anyone have any idea?

update: It works when I make the file pattern as /tmp/delta.csv. Looks like a permission issue but no errors in the logs.

> Tailer Progress: Tailer has parsed 0 records (0 bytes), transformed 0
>   records, skipped 0 records, and has successfully sent 0 records to
>   destination. 2017-06-22 18:12:03.671+0000 
>   (Agent.MetricsEmitter RUNNING)
>   com.amazon.kinesis.streaming.agent.Agent [INFO] Agent: Progress: 0
>   records parsed (0 bytes), and 0 records sent successfully to
>   destinations. Uptime: 300020ms

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, I was able to solve it by doing the following:

1. moving the data to be sent to the kinesis firehose stream (a bunch of CSV files) from ~/ec2-user/out-data to another directory:

   ```
   mv *.csv /tmp/out-data
   ```
2. edit the agent.json file so that the agent starts reading at the beginning of the file- here is my agent.json file:

   ```
   {
     "cloudwatch.emitMetrics": true,
     "firehose.endpoint": "firehose.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com",
     "flows": [
       {
         "filePattern": "/tmp/out-data/trx_headers_2017*",
         "deliveryStream": "TestDeliveryStream",
         "initialPosition": "START_OF_FILE"
       }
     ]
   }
   ```

my guess is that your Delta.csv file is being written to so the kinesis agent is checking the end of the file and finding no new records, if you add the `"initialPosition" : "START_OF_FILE"` fix it will start parsing at the beginning of file.

Answer (score 0):

Moving your data to /tmp/logs, /var/logs will fix the issue. Do not leave data under /ec2-user.

Link to the issue: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-agent/issues/58

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. I solved it by doing the following.

1. Moving data to `var/logs/<anyfolder or file>`
2. Make sure the file is closed after writing. I have used `f.close()` after writing log to a file when using python.