# Kinesis agent not sending .log files through firehose

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis-firehose, amazon-kinesis-agent

I've setup a Kinesis firehose and the installed the Kinesis agent as described in the [AWS docs](https://d1.awsstatic.com/Projects/P4113850/aws-projects_build-log-analytics-solution-on-aws.pdf).  I can get test data through to the S3 bucket, but the Kinesis agent won't send any .log files through.  I suspect a problem connecting the agent to the firehose.

My `/etc/aws-kinesis/agent.json` file is below.  I've also tried with the `"firehose.endpoint"` without the `https://` but I still can't get any data through.

I've verified that the aws-kinesis-agent service is running.

I'm not using the kinesis.endpoint/kinesisStream, but I've left the flow in the agent.json file.  Could this be a problem?

What am I missing?

```
{
  "cloudwatch.emitMetrics": true,
  "kinesis.endpoint": "",
  "firehose.endpoint": "https://firehose.us-west-2.amazonaws.com",

  "flows": [
    {
      "filePattern": "/home/ec2-user/src/Fake-Apache-Log-Generator/*.log*",
      "kinesisStream": "yourkinesisstream",
      "partitionKeyOption": "RANDOM"
    },
    {
      "filePattern": "/home/ec2-user/src/Fake-Apache-Log-Generator/*.log*",
      "deliveryStream": "apachelogfilesdeliverystream"
    }
  ]
}
```

EDIT:

The log file at `/var/log/aws-kinesis-agent/aws-kinesis-agent.log` showed 0 records being parsed.  The log message led me to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44706843/kinesis-agent-not-parsing-the-file), and I made the recommended fixes.  In addition I had to remove the flow for kinesis from the /etc/aws-kinesis/agent.json file to avoid an Exception that showed up in the log files.

Botton line is that the aws-kinesis-agent can't read files from /home/ec2-user/ or its subdirectories, and you have to fix up the agent.json file.

Comment: You can check the agent's log files at `/var/log/aws-kinesis` to see figure out the error.

Answer (score 1):

Kinesis agent is not able to read the logs from a file which is at `/home/ec2-user/<any-file>` due to some permissions issue. Try changing your logs location to `/tmp/logs/<log-file>`.

Answer (score 0):

Add the kinesis agent to the sudoers group:

```
sudo usermod -aG sudo aws-kinesis-agent-user
```

Another possibility is data flow, see this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/64610780/5697992